# Event Dispatch Thread in GWT?

Tags: gwt, event-dispatch-thread

When writing Swing or AWT applications, I'm aware that GUI changes should always be done in the EDT. How does this translate to writing GWT applications?

I'm looking at a scenario when I call the following.

```
myRequestBuilder.sendRequest(myRequestDate, myRequestCallback)
```

**myRequestCallback**  modifies the GUI. Having such a construct in Swing, I would make sure that the **myRequestCallback** invokes the EDT for the GUI changes. Does GWT require me to do something similar as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the web (in browsers), it's dead easy: everything always executes in the event dispatch thread.

See also http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/